# res document class cannot compile

Tags: resume, cv, missing

Is the res document class for resume still working? I never had problems with res before. However, recently I was not able to compile my cv.

I have miktex on windows 10. Even for the below MWE, got  "
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}."

Thanks for any advice.

```
\documentclass[line, margin]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{Max Burstein}
\address{1234 Herp Derp Lane \\ Rabble, FL 34343 \\ (516) 516-5165}

\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `res.cls` is obsolete for a very long time and should not be used anymore.

Comment: do not really want to rewrite the text. any like for like replacement class for res.cls?  thanks.

Comment: Do youo like the look, or the way data is input? There are so many CV templates out there you can choose from, fro good to bad quality.

Comment: I like "plain" look resume. Some of the templates I found are too modern for my taste without substantial modifications to the code.

Comment: If you want *plain*, you don't need to use any template. :-)

Comment: touche....too lazy to translate my customised res CV using another class. any idea how to resurrect the res.cls?

Comment: Actually I can't replicate your problem. Got `res.cls` from CTAN and the above code works fine for me. Also on Windows 10 and Miktex 2.9

Comment: @MarkStarbucks: Use Johannes_B's recommendation and try to omit the `res.cls`; Despite of this, using your small document above I have no problem to compile it with TexLive 2017 on Linux

Comment: Even the wikibook warns about res.cls -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`res.cls` is not in texlive for licencing reasons but you can get the file from

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res

and save it in the same folder as your document, then the posted document in your question runs without error.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked..didn't realise they took it out during one of the updates! Thank you!